# Positioning of words in the header, footer positioning,

Tags: html, css

that's my first site with html and css. I'm doing a personal website and i have problems:
1) right positioning of words in the header
2) footer positioning
 the code is:

```
<head>
  <meta cherset='UTF-8'/>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
</head>

<body>

  <header class='header'>

<ul class='header__menu animate'>
  <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="HOME.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="HOBBY E PASSIONI.html">HOBBY E PASSIONI</a></li>
  <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="CURRICULUM.html">CURRICULUM</a></li>
  <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="CONTATTI.html">CONTATTI</a></li>
</ul>
</header>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>Gabriele Minosa</h1>
<br><br><br>

<div class='img'>
<img src="1111.png">
</div>

<figcaption> text...
</figcaption>

<br><br>

<footer class='footer'>
<p>&copy; 2020 Gabriele Minosa. TUTTI I DIRITTI RISERVATI</p>
</footer>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS**********

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  height: 1200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000000;   /*colore scritte*/
  background: #eee;  /*COLORE ESTERNO PAGINA WEB*/
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #5D6063;    /*COLORE SCRITTE INTESTAZIONE*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


.header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #d6d6d2;
}


.header__menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
  }

h1 {
  color:#949da6;
  font-size:40;
  text-align: center;
}



figcaption, footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

if anyone could tell me, apart from those two questions, what other changes I can make and what other mistakes I made I would be grateful..that's my first time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please focus on one specific problem at a time (which often only requires a small section of your code) instead of asking several questions at once or requesting general feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align the menu to the right inside a flex container, you can change the justification of the flex items by using `justify-content: flex-end;` - this positions the elements horizontally at the end of the container.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #d6d6d2;
}
```

In regards to your second question regarding footer positioning, what are you attempting to achieve?

---

In the below code snippet, which I believe achieves your desired results, there's a couple of changes I've made;

- I wrapped your page content (the stuff in between the header and footer) in a `<main>` tag. This tag is given a min-height value of 80vh - or 80% of the height of the viewport. This will make sure that your footer is towards the bottom of the page. If you have a page with less content you may want to change this to 90 or even 100.
- The display property for `header__menu` `<ul>` has been set to flex. Justify content is used here but this time setting the value to space-between.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000000;   /*colore scritte*/
  background: #eee;  /*COLORE ESTERNO PAGINA WEB*/
}

main{ 
  min-height: 90vh; 
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #5D6063;    /*COLORE SCRITTE INTESTAZIONE*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #d6d6d2;
}

.header__menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.header__menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color:#949da6;
  font-size:40;
  text-align: center;
}



figcaption, footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class='header'>

  <ul class='header__menu animate'>
    <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="HOME.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="HOBBY E PASSIONI.html">HOBBY E PASSIONI</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="CURRICULUM.html">CURRICULUM</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu__item"><a href="CONTATTI.html">CONTATTI</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>

  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <h1>Gabriele Minosa</h1>
  <br><br><br>

  <div class='img'>
    <img src="1111.png">
  </div>

  <figcaption> Gabriele Minosa (Taranto, 12 Gennaio 1991) è un perito informatico con la passione per l’informatica fin da bambino.<br>
    Dopo aver imparato,da autodidatta, a gestire l'hardware ed il software dei pc, allarga la sua curiosità al mondo dell'innovazione <br>
    e della programmazione web. Non essendo particolarmente stimolato dal contenuto troppo generalizzato del percorso universitario, <br>
    dopo alcune esperienze lavorative e svariati concorsi, è attualmente uno studente di Front End Development di start2impact, una <br>
    startup di Roma che propone percorsi innovativi sulla programmazione e sulle nuove tecnologie e rende potenzialmente più immediato <br>
    e diretto l'inserimento nel mondo del lavoro.
  </figcaption>

</main>

<br><br>

<footer class='footer'>
  <p>&copy; 2020 Gabriele Minosa. TUTTI I DIRITTI RISERVATI</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: hi, i put flex end but i want the writing in the center of the page and well spaced from each other. About second question i want footer down at the end of the page, not in the middle..don't understand why my footer is in the middle of the page

Comment: @CoachMino check out the code snippet above, is that what you're going for? I'll update the post with an explanation now :)

Comment: ok did it and solved for the header but i want to see  the footer more down in the page

Comment: @CoachMino Play around with the `min-height` value inside your CSS rule for main. If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider marking this answer as accepted :)